# css, how to inspect element mobile view on pc

Tags: html, css

I want to use inspect element on pc to view how the site looks like on mobile, the feature of Chrome and firefox not working as I tested my website on iphone I found the height of a box is bigger than the height on samsung, I don't know where is the issue and how to fix it while I don't have a way to inspect element as a real iphone on pc

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it has to do with the rendering of the page, witch is different on an iPhone then it is on a Android device. So thats why Chrome can look different when u use the element inspector and view as an iPhone X for example.

Comment: If you are on VS Code, you can try Live Server extension. That will give you a local server and you can open that server on your mobile phone using you IP. It will give live preview. I hope, It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Click Ctrl + Shift + M to enter responsive design mode where you can view the website in mobile view and tablet view.
You can learn the basics of responsive web design [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive)

Comment: I have been clear from the beginning, and my question is clear, the way to use inspect element is  not the same view as in mobile

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to do this:

1. Actually,You can do this with Chrome,Press F12,and press this button:
   [image]
   And select the class of mobile device:

[image]

2. Or You can download a `Mobile emulator` in your PC.

Comment: @Ash So if you don't mind to download an Moblie emulator in your PC,you can try it.

Comment: which is the best one?

Comment: @Ash I don't know,But if you just use it to inspect the page,I think anything is ok.

Comment: Chrome on an iphone does not behave like a pc chrome version, so this can help for basic cases but it's not reliable

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no accurate way to do this on windows PC, using Mac safari you can do accurate inspection and debugging of your page on real iOS device.

If you have a Mac system you can connect iOS device to Mac and using Mac Safari you can inspect iOS web page elements.

First activate Web Inspector in Safari->Advanced settings on the iPhone or another iOS device.

Connect the iPhone to your Mac computer with a cable and open the Mac's Safari, where you enable the ​Develop menu in Safari's Advanced Preferences.

From the develop menu on Mac safari you will be able to access mobile safari web elements.

Comment: I dont have mac

Comment: Completely unrelated to this issue but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Bhoju!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the script from here and paste in your mobile browser:-
for Your reference **[click here](https://javascript-html-5.blogspot.com/2022/06/how-to-open-inspect-element-on-any.html)**

```
javascript:(()=>{
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda";
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.onload=(()=>eruda.init());
})()
```